# How to preview apps on iPad?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, prototype, prototyping

I am using xcode to develop a prototype application. Nothing too fancy, just slide effects and other simple gestures. Mostly moving images around the screen.

I can preview the app on my laptop using ios simulator, but how do I take the prototype to the iPad for a more realistic view?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to join a paid [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/) or, if possible, the [iOS University Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/university/).

Then, you will have to create and install provisioning profiles using the steps in this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/10-Configuring_Development_and_Distribution_Assets/identities_and_devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW1).

After that, you can test on iOS devices the same way you test on the Simulator.

**Edit**

> Alleviate the need to go to the iOS Provisioning Portal every time you want to add a device to your provisioning profile by using automatic provisioning.

An easier way to install provisioning profiles is to let Xcode manage them for you. See the paragraph *"To provision a device automatically for development"* in [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Devices/Devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH12-SW4) guide for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This process requires a developer account with Apple - and you have to go through the Provisioning Portal to setup your provisioning profile.  Apple recently came up with a great getting started guide:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/gettingstarted/

Read the section on "Installing and Testing Apps on iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch".